# Where can I get the google maps location marker image?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Does anyone know where I can find the google maps location marker resource (seen below) from the iphone native API? I'd like to use in my JS API-3 application..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.google.com/mobile/images/gmm/blue_dot.jpg) which looks extremely similiar.  I suspect the actual blue icon is an Apple thing.